# DateTime to string conversion showing error

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to convert `DateTime` to `string` with custom format. But it's showing me `LINQ` error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is my code in controller:

```
public ActionResult DaywiseData(DateTime date)
{
    try
    {
        var att = db.Attendances
                 .Where(d => d.Date == date)
                 .Select(s => new AttendanceViewModel
                  {
                      Date = s.Date,
                      aa = DateTime.Parse(s.InTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm tt"),  //Error is not showing after removing this line
                      InTime = s.InTime,
                      OutTime = s.OutTime,
                      EmployeeName = s.Employee.Name,
                      EmployeeUsername = s.Employee.Username
                  })
                  .ToList();
         return Json(att);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return Json(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you update the answer?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal OP already posted the error..

Comment: Error given on top.

Comment: Why are you doing all this parsing and formatting at all? What is the type of `InTime` and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jon Skeet.. I want to get the time only from datetime from database. Hete `InTime` is `DateTime` type variable

Comment: why not just `s.InTime.ToString("HH:mm tt")` then?

Comment: But why do you need that? You've got it already as part of your `InTime` property... and even if you *do* need that, why convert the `DateTime` to a string and then parse it again? `s.InTime.ToString("HH:mm tt")` would make slightly more sense, although I don't think you really want `HH` if you're using `tt`. (Do you really want 7pm to be `19:00 pm`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ is translated into SQL query which does not support ToString(). Leave it as DateTime and later convert to string. Something like this

```
public ActionResult DaywiseData(DateTime date)
{
    try
    {
        var att = db.Attendances
                 .Where(d => d.Date == date)
                 .Select(s => new AttendanceViewModel
                  {
                      Date = s.Date,
                      DateTime = s.InTime, //dateTime property
                      DateTimeString = string.Empty //string property
                      InTime = s.InTime,
                      OutTime = s.OutTime,
                      EmployeeName = s.Employee.Name,
                      EmployeeUsername = s.Employee.Username
                  })
                  .ToList();
         att.ForEach(a => a.DateTimeString = a.DateTime.ToString("HH:mm tt"));

         return Json(att);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return Json(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(s.InTime.ToString())` isn't required, `s.InTime` is already a `DateTime`.

Comment: What to do if `InTime` is `Nullable`?

Comment: att.ForEach(a => a.DateTimeString = a.DateTime.HasValue ? a.DateTime.ToString("HH:mm tt") : string.Empty);

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because the `Expression` inside your select is converted to SQL and run on the Database server and that's why it doesn't recognize the `DateTime.Parse(s.InTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm tt")` method. You have two choices here:

Update your code to materialize the result of your query before doing the `.Select`:

```
var att = db.Attendances
     .Where(d => d.Date == date)
     .ToList() // Here
     .Select(s => new AttendanceViewModel
      {
          Date = s.Date,
          aa = DateTime.Parse(s.InTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm tt"),  //Error is not showing after removing this line
          InTime = s.InTime,
          OutTime = s.OutTime,
          EmployeeName = s.Employee.Name,
          EmployeeUsername = s.Employee.Username
      })
      .ToList();
return Json(att);
```

Or use @Nino's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using SqlFunctions.StringConvert;
Like this;

```
aa = DateTime.Parse(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(s.InTime)),  //Error is not showing after removing this line
```